# How can I speed up the animations when using FluidKit?

Tags: c#, wpf, animation, timespan, duration

I've using [FluidKit](http://tanguay.info/web/index.php?pg=codeExamples&id=280) in a WPF application and would like to speed up the animations.

```
SlideTransition slideTransition = Resources["SlideTransition"] as SlideTransition;
slideTransition.Direction = Direction.LeftToRight;
slideTransition.Duration = new Duration(new System.TimeSpan(1000)); //does not work
TransitionContainer.Transition = slideTransition;
```

It has a "Duration" property which is of type Duration which expects a TimeSpan, but any timespan I give it just causes there to be no animation.

**How can I set a duration to control the speed of the animation?**

(If anyone is looking for answers to this, I also [posted it](http://fluidkit.codeplex.com/Thread/View.aspx?ThreadId=72644) on the codeplex forum.)

Answer (score 0):

this works:

```
slideTransition.Duration = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(200);
```

Answer (score 0):

The `TimeSpan` constructor invoked in your example is the one taking a `long`, which corresponds to ticks. A time span tick unit represents 100-nanosecond. You're effectively starting an animation during 100 microseconds, which is why you're seeing no animation at all.